# Ничего не получается установить с помощью PIP(python)

Tags: python, pip, install

Ввожу
`pip install livewires`
и выдает ошибку

> invalid syntax

я ввожу команду по пути
`С:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.752.0_x64_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.9.exe`
Что делать?

Comment: pip install нужно делать через командную строку(win+r и далее вводите cmd). Вы же вводите в интерпретаторе питона

Comment: Там же не только invalid syntax пишет, приведите полный текст ошибки. Вообще, если устанавливали python из магазина micoroft windows, попробуйте его удалить и установить с официального сайта (python.org) в `c:\python` (не в папку пользователя, не в program files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вводите это в REPL!
А надо в командную строку

```
pip install livewires
```

Через REPL будет работать так:

```
import os
os.system('pip install livewires')
```

И самое главное: Удалите питон из microsoft store и поставьте с официального сайта: [python.org](https://python.org)

Comment: `И самое главное: Удалите питон из microsoft store и поставьте с официального сайта: python.org` — почему?

Comment: Потому что с ним может не устанавливаться часть библиотек. И могут быть баги.